# ModelBuilder - Line and box graphs - overlap doubt

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I am creating a model using ModelBuilder, in which there are a lot of arrows due to the workflow:

[image]

Is there an option for these lines of the arrows to be below the boxes?

Comment: Are you using the ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro or of ArcMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can click on the line segment of the arrows to add points to the line, which you can drag around to reposition the line.  You can add multiple midpoints.

[image]